# ¿Como puedo generar claves dinamicas en un array asociativo con ciclos for anidados en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código

```
var optionVacio="";
var arrayDinamico = [];
        arrayDinamico = $( this ).serializeArray();
        for(let x=1;x<=10;x++){
            for(let y=1;y<=3;y++){
                for(let z=1;z<=3;z++){
                    arrayDinamico.push(Bx_INCISO_y_z:optionVacio);
                }
            }
        }
```

Con los ciclos for quiero que se vaya generando un array como el siguiente para no tener que poner todo manualmente. Debido a que el valor de x, y, z será dinámico, por eso necesito que ese array se genere de manera automática

```
valuesCalificacionPreescolar1.push({B1_INCISO_1_1:optionVacio,B1_INCISO_1_2:optionVacio,B1_INCISO_1_3:optionVacio,B1_INCISO_2_1:optionVacio,B1_INCISO_2_2:optionVacio,B1_INCISO_2_3:optionVacio});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres puedes usar dos `for` asi:

```js
var optionVacio="";
var arrayDinamico = {};
        
        
            for(let y=1;y<=3;y++){
                for(let z=1;z<=3;z++){
                    var index = "Bx_INCISO_" +y+"_"+z;
                    arrayDinamico[index]=optionVacio;
                }
            }
       
        console.log(arrayDinamico);
```